# Hiding a css class permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hiding the css class .pds-pd-link. This class styles the link www.polldaddy.com . The link is hidden. When the user votes and clicks "Return To Poll" the link www.polldaddy.com is viewable again. I don't think there is any way to hide this permanently without modyifying source code of poll ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/2/

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pds-pd-link").hide();
        $(".a2a_dd.pds-share").hide();
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6343621/">New Poll</a></noscript>
```

Comment: `.hide` will hide the element; **not sure what do you mean by permanently** do you mean remove the element? Sorry if I sound thick `:)` , cheers

Comment: @yep, remove the element. No, not thick, far from it. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.pds-pd-link {
    display: none !important;
}
```

​
Seems to do the job

http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/7/

Comment: Might as well remove the `$(".pds-pd-link").hide();`.

Comment: Didn't even know that was there

Comment: I'm sorry if that's the case. I'll check it out when I get the chance

Comment: @user701254: still works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Codemonkey it seems fine actually now again, im not sure what the issue was. thanks